# How to store data for fast access in a MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, sql, datatables, database-performance, sqlperformance

Suppose I have this fields:

```
first name, last name, city, state, zip, lat, lng
```

I'm trying to find a way to store the data so I can do queries like:

- search by name or name & city
- search by radius

Suppose I have millions of records, not sure if the best option is to put them all in one single table.

I could split them by state, but then I'll have to do a bunch of joins when searching.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The more joins you have the slower things will get. If the data needs to be structured in a relational way for long term maintainability and extensibility than do so.

That MySQL table does not have to be where your fast search queries against.

You can MapReduce with Hadoop + Hive for high speed querying of lots of data, or, probably even easier to implement, you can build a Solr index that you query against.

In general, you will not achieve a very fast searchable large data set in MySQL or any relational database, MySQL is a great relational database store and will be fast for a while. But, depending on your searches and number of records, you will need the data to be grouped and aggregated differently and that is where something like a Solr or a NoSQL persistence/view of the data can get you the speeds you need.

Answer (score 0):

A single table, with

```
INDEX(last_name, first_name, city)
INDEX(lat)
```

The first index handles your first pair of searches.  The last one *partially* helps the search by radius; it might be good enough for only a million rows.

For a lot more rows, "nearest" requires a much [*more complex approach*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/latlng) .

Some of the other approaches will simply brute-force search the entire list.  That is *not* good for "nearest".